# User comments on course page on frontend in Tutor LMS

Tags: comments, lms

In wordpress, on the frontend, in Tutor LMS on a course page, how can we have a section(at the bottom) where users can comment; like in Learpress?

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

By default, the Tutor LMS doesn’t have a comment form for the course details page. The comments is removed based on majority customer’s feedback because this is not a blog post page but a product page. However, you still can add a comment form very easily just by editing two files and following the steps:

1. Open this file /tutor/classes/Post_types.php,

   -In this file, you will find this code `array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'author'),`

   -You need to replace the code with this code `array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'author', 'comments'),`
2. Now you need to edit this file
   /tutor/templates/single/course/instructors.php

   -In this file before this code `<?php } do_action( 'tutor_course/single/enrolled/after/instructors' );`

   -You need to add this code `<?php comments_template( '', true ); ?>`
3. Now you need to edit your course and enable comments for the course. to enable comments check the provided screenshot https://prnt.sc/26q0usm

Thank you

Comment: Thank you sooo much Rashed, i'll try this out and let you know...

Comment: Dear Rashed, I did as you guided and was able to get the comment section in the admin panel when editing a course. See this (https://prnt.sc/26qpxhi). But can't see the comment section on course page in the front end (https://theamazingchild.com/courses/spoken-english-camp-for-girls/); please help...

Comment: It’s my pleasure. I checked your course and I see that the instructor section is hidden on your course page. Please enable the instructor section. Because the comment form was added to the instructor section file.

Comment: ok, thanks. Done and working now!